# pthread static linking with application in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, pthreads, static-libraries, pthreads-win32

I want to pthread lib statically linked with my application so that at other target without install pthread lib my .exe will run.

For that I have add **pthreadVC.lib in Linker->input->additional dependency** of visual studio and also given correct path for lib.

Also I add this code `#define PTW32_STATIC_LIB` in my thread.h file before `#include <pthread.h>`

My application build successfully and running on same machine. But I trying to run on other target I got error **pthreadVC.dll is missing** .

Please tell me where I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case i was not having static lib and i was trying to do static link with dynamic lib. Following are steps to do static linking .

1. Download source code of [Pthread_Win32](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/pthread-win32) and build it with visual studio.
2. So now you will have static lib (pthread_lib.lib) probably at path .........\pthread-win32-master\pthread-win32-master\bin\Win32_MSVC2013.Release
3. In your application go into project properties mainly 
   `Linker->input->additional dependency` and add `pthread_lib.lib`.
4. Also add path of `pthread_lib.lib` into visual studio properties `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`.
5. Add this code `#define PTW32_STATIC_LIB` in header file.